# If the CreateJS library supports the JSON output formats of Texture Packer

Tags: javascript, easeljs, texturepacker

I'd been using CreateJS for a little time. I got trouble to load an image which is made by Texture Packer, and I got the JSON file like this:

```
{"frames": [

{
"filename": "aim_dot",
"frame": {"x":118,"y":4,"w":76,"h":76},
"rotated": false,
"trimmed": false,
"spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":76,"h":76},
"sourceSize": {"w":76,"h":76}
},
{
"filename": "boundary",
"frame": {"x":4,"y":385,"w":250,"h":100},
"rotated": false,
"trimmed": false,
"spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":250,"h":100},
"sourceSize": {"w":250,"h":100}
}]

}
```

When a Bitmap represents an Image like this:

```
 var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("imagePath.jpg");
```

But if the image is an image sprites,could i use the bitmap like css sprite?

Comment: <code>function showStartMenu() {
    //Method 1
    var sprites_0 = {
        "images": ['image.png'],        
        "animations": {
            "slice1": {"frames": [0]}
        },

        "frames": [
        // x, y, width, height, imageIndex*, regX*, regY*
            [916, 101, 84, 84, 0, 0, 0]
        ]
    };

    var spriteslist = new c.SpriteSheet(sprites_0);
    var slices= new c.Sprite(spriteslist);

    stage.addChild(slices);
    slices.gotoAndStop('slice1');
    stage.update();
}<code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the `SpriteSheet`-Class: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheet.html

In TexturePacker you can chose EaselJS as a output format, so the JSON can be used for EaselJS `SpriteSheet` without further modifications. Another good way to generate EaselJS SpriteSheets would be spritesheet.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/spritesheet-js-monkiki-fork).